# How to add items to the custom array list in android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Hi I have developed an android application where I'm retrieving the categories from mysql and setting them to the custom array list and displaying them as buttons.

Now I wanted to bring the same categories from local sqlite database and display them as buttons.
But in First situation I have created a custom list array and I'm assigning the response and adding the items to that list and displaying as buttons.

But when I'm trying to retrieve them from local sqlite database I'm not getting how to add the values to the array list

This is how I'm retrieving from mysql

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resp) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(resp ==null) {
            if (categoriesResp != null) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+categoriesResp, 5000).show();
                updateUi(categoriesResp.response);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "Something went wrong",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else

            if(!Utils.isNetConnected(Categories.this))
                Utils.showDialog(Categories.this);
            else
            Toast.makeText(Categories.this, resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

This is my Uiupdate()  method

```
    private void Uiupdate(List<Category> response) {
    int i = 0;
    for(Category category:response){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_category, null, false);
        Button button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonCategory);
        button.setText(category.CategoryName);
        button.setTag(category.CategoryID);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Utils.isNetConnected(Categories.this)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Categories.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("categoryId", (String) v.getTag());
                    intent.putExtra("categoryName", ((Button) v).getText());

                    startActivity(intent);
                }else
                    Utils.showDialog(Categories.this);
            }
        });
        if(i%2 == 0)
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_with_arrow);
        else
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field_with_arrow);
        i++;
        categoriesContainer.addView(row);
    }

}
```

This is my local sqlite method

```
 public void loadCategories()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loaded", 5000).show();
    db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("tafrider", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName FROM categories WHERE EventID= 0  and status= 1 ",null);
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    while(c.moveToNext()){ 
       categoryName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CategoryName"));

       Category c1 = new Category();
       c1.CategoryName= categoryName;
       Category.add(c1);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+categoryName, 5000).show();

    } 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+categories.size(), 5000).show();
    updateUi(categories);

}
```

Here I'm facing the problem with categories.add(categoryName) its showing error 
How to solve this..?

Comment: " its showing error" what error?

Comment: @codeMagic The method add(Category) in the type List<Category> is not applicable for the arguments (String) this is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like

```
List<Categories> categories = new ArrayList<Categories>();
while(c.moveToNext()){ 
   categoryName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CategoryName"));
Categories categoryObject=new Categories();
 categoryObject.CategoryName=categoryName;

    categories.add(categoryObject);
   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+categoryName, 5000).show();

}
```

categoryName is type of string and you are adding it to list that is of category

```
for(Category category:response){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_category, null, false);
    Button button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonCategory);
    button.setText(category.CategoryName);
    button.setTag(category.CategoryID);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(Utils.isNetConnected(Categories.this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Categories.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("categoryId", (String) v.getTag());
                intent.putExtra("categoryName", ((Button) v).getText());

                startActivity(intent);
            }else
                Utils.showDialog(Categories.this);
        }
    });
    if(i%2 == 0)
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_with_arrow);
    else
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.field_with_arrow);
    i++;
    categoriesContainer.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this its showing error

Comment: what error it is showing?

Comment: The method Uiupdate(List<Category>) in the type Categories is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)

Comment: change it to Uiupdate(List<String> response)

Comment: Actually i have created custom Category like this                 public class Category {
    public String CategoryID="", CategoryName = "";
}

Comment: ok em goona change my answer and then check it

Comment: now try it i have changed the code

Comment: its showing an error like this The method add(Categories) is undefined for the type Categories

Comment: post you updated code

Comment: write categories.add(c1); insted of Category.add(c1);

Comment: Yeah its working now my doubt is will this attach to button and can I generate buttons according to my code?

Comment: yes it will if you try it

Comment: sure and also thanks for your patience and help

Comment: my Pleasure have a great life..

Comment: also I will not leave you unless and untill my problem gets solved just kidding Tq

Comment: no problem after postinga question just paste link here

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you initialised the `List` with `Category` like this `List<Category> list = new ArrayList<Category>();`. But you trying to add `String` instead of`Category`. What you need to do is either change the initialisation to `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` or add `Category` instead of `String`.

**EDIT**
In Response to your comment.No you not adding Category. In your `loadCategories()` method i seen this code

```
while(c.moveToNext()){ 
   categoryName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CategoryName"));// This is String not a category. You need to change here
   categories.add(categoryName); // Adding as String
}
```

Change this to

```
while(c.moveToNext()){ 
   categoryName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CategoryName"))  
   // Init Category 
   Categories caObj=new Categories();
   caObj.yourCategoryName=categoryName;
   categories.add(caObj); // Now you adding as Cateogry
}
```

Comment: I have added Category only but its showing the errors

Comment: Check my updated answer. Hope it will be clear for you

Comment: its showing an error like this The method add(Categories) is undefined for the type Categories